# MySQL find rows based on another query

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have 2 tables `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`.
I was able to run this SQL query
`` SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = 'waterfront' AND meta_value = 'No'; ``

And this is the result of the query which is great.

```
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key   | meta_value |  |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+--+
| 67      | 1       | waterfront | No         |  |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+--+
| 1122    | 90      | waterfront | No         |  |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+--+
```

**How can I get the rows from the `wp_posts` table with the `post_id` that I'm getting on the first query.**

I thought to try another query, something like:
`` SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE id IN (1, 90) ``

But I probably do it wrong, it's not like I can run the first query and save it to a variable and make another query based on that.

Comment: Use a [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). For a more specific answer, please provide more specific details, like DDL (Create table statements) and sample data DML (insert statements).

Comment: I don't know if I can do it with join because I'm getting the post_id only after the first query, that's why I'm asking

Comment: You don't need to know the specific post_id. The JOIN does that for you. Just INNER JOIN the two tables on the shared columns (`id`  = `post_id`) and and add the `where` clause.

Comment: `SELECT wp.* FROM wp_posts wp INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm ON wpm.post_id = wp.id AND meta_key = 'waterfront' AND meta_value = 'No';`
or
`SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'waterfront' AND meta_value = 'No');`

Comment: `this is not just a simple join`  Yes... it is.

Comment: What @SOS meant is that StackOverflow might possibly `Close` your question if you do not provide _more specific details, like DDL (Create table statements) and sample data DML (insert statements)_ so that readers would be able in advance to test a statement like _
SELECT pm.* FROM wp_postmeta pm INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON p.post_id = pm.post_id WHERE pm.meta_key = 'waterfront' AND pm.meta_value = 'No'
;_ before they'd post it as an Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve what you want by running one of the queries below:

- using *inner join*

```sql
SELECT wp.* FROM wp_posts wp INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm ON wpm.post_id = wp.id AND meta_key = 'waterfront' AND meta_value = 'No';
```

- using *in*

```sql
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'waterfront' AND meta_value = 'No');
```